# Multiple images with improper captions and their positioning

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats

I have 12 images of different sizes which I added in my latex document. But their positions are somewhat random and the captions are also not at proper positions. I would like to have 4 rows of images in 3 columns and their captions below. How do I do that? Here is what I have tried:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf}   
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[lofdepth,lotdepth]{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\subfloat[][22q11]{
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{22q11.jpg}
\label{fig:subfig1}}
\qquad
\subfloat[][Angelman]{
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{angelman.jpg}
\label{fig:subfig2}}
\subfloat[]Apert]{
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{apert.jpg}
\label{fig:subfig3}}
\qquad
\subfloat[][CDL]{
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{CDL.jpg}
\label{fig:subfig4}}

\label{fig:globfig}
\subfloat[]Down]{
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{down.jpg}
\label{fig:subfig1}}
\qquad
\subfloat[][Marfan]{
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{marfan.jpg}
\label{fig:subfig1}}
\qquad
\subfloat[][Progeria]{
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{progeria.jpg}
\label{fig:subfig1}}
\qquad
\subfloat[][Sotos]{
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{sotos.jpg}
\label{fig:subfig1}}
\qquad
\subfloat[][Turner]{
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{turner.jpg}
\label{fig:subfig1}}
\qquad
\subfloat[][Williams]{
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{williams.jpg}
\label{fig:subfig1}}
\qquad
\subfloat[][FragileX]{
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{fragileX.jpg}
\label{fig:subfig1}}
\qquad
\subfloat[][Treacher Collins]{
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{Treacher_collins.jpg}
\label{fig:subfig1}}
\qquad
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is how the images look like in my document:[image]

Comment: Please consider using a general class like `article`. We don't have these pictures, so please use `draft` mode or `MWE` example images for `MWE`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some missing opening brackets `[` in your code. Also, there is a missing `\qquad` and no manual `\\`s for new lines. If you do that, you could come up with:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[lofdepth,lotdepth]{subfig}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \subfloat[][22q11]{
            \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{22q11.jpg}
            \label{fig:subfig1}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[][Angelman]{
            \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{angelman.jpg}
            \label{fig:subfig2}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[][Apert]{
            \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{apert.jpg}
            \label{fig:subfig3}}
        \\
        \subfloat[][CDL]{
            \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{CDL.jpg}
            \label{fig:subfig4}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[][Down]{
            \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{down.jpg}
            \label{fig:subfig1}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[][Marfan]{
            \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{marfan.jpg}
            \label{fig:subfig1}}
        \\
        \subfloat[][Progeria]{
            \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{progeria.jpg}
            \label{fig:subfig1}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[][Sotos]{
            \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{sotos.jpg}
            \label{fig:subfig1}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[][Turner]{
            \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{turner.jpg}
            \label{fig:subfig1}}
        \\
        \subfloat[][Williams]{
            \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{williams.jpg}
            \label{fig:subfig1}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[][FragileX]{
            \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{fragileX.jpg}
            \label{fig:subfig1}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[][Treacher Collins]{
            \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{Treacher_collins.jpg}
            \label{fig:subfig1}}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**edit:** Assuming you want aligned pictures of the same height, the width of your pictures varies. You can use a table to get the (probably) desired result (this time I used a MWE configuration, please get used to change your code to a MWE if you post a question):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[lofdepth,lotdepth]{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \subfloat[][22q11]{
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:subfig1}}%
    &\subfloat[][Angelman]{
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-1x1}
        \label{fig:subfig2}}%
    &\subfloat[][Apert]{
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-10x16}
        \label{fig:subfig3}}%
    \\
    \subfloat[][CDL]{
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-9x16}
        \label{fig:subfig4}}%
    &\subfloat[][Down]{
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:subfig1}}%
    &\subfloat[][Marfan]{
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-1x1}
        \label{fig:subfig1}}%
    \\
    \subfloat[][Progeria]{
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-golden}
        \label{fig:subfig1}}%
    &\subfloat[][Sotos]{
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-golden-upright}
        \label{fig:subfig1}}%
    &\subfloat[][Turner]{
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:subfig1}}%
    \\
    \subfloat[][Williams]{
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:subfig1}}%
    &\subfloat[][FragileX]{
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:subfig1}}%
    &\subfloat[][Treacher Collins]{
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:subfig1}}%
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: That seems to have taken care of all the alignments. Thank you! Is there a way to make their sizes similar? I mean resize them to the same size? Or do I have to do that manually?

Comment: @ZER-0-NE Could you specify what you mean by same size? Since they don't have the same format, this is not clear. You could adjust the height to be equal (in case this is what you want, use `height=...` rather than `width` as argument in includegraphics).

Comment: same dimensions? I'll check that out.

Comment: The ratio is not equal. So I assume you want them to have the same height.

Comment: @ZER-0-NE see my edited answer, maybe this is what you want.